# Vitural host creation in xampp

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I like to configure my first web application in virtual host.

Do you have any idea and suggestion please share it.

Comment: check out xampplite (portable) for your staging.

Answer (score 0):

Open \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-hosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:\work\myapplication"
ServerName myapplication.dev
<Directory "D:\work\myapplication">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

addition to this open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

write

127.0.0.1       myapplication.dev

when you will open a URL http://myapplication.dev in browser it will open your project.

Comment: i don't have any permission to write in system32 folder files, so you have any other idea to achieve my need.

Comment: are you setting up on local server or shared server?

Comment: then in local pc you will need to get access of system32 try to open as an adminitroator by right clicking on the file. there will be one to open in edit mode.

Comment: i already found this,but i want to need with out touch the system32 files, do you have any other idea to get my need

Comment: I don't think it will be feasible without modifying the system32 files.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to System32 directory means, you can place your application files in PHP's root directory and access it using the Localhost URL.